# let user create different button actions in shinydashboard app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to build a shiny app that allows the user to select some columns to filter a `data.table`.

My real data has ~110 columns and the columns are `numeric`, `character`, `factor`, `integer`

I want to have a pre-selected filter in the sidebar panel but also to have a `+` button to allow the user to create custom filters based on the columns. I don't know if this can be done in shiny or not, I have read about `insertUI` and `removeUI` but I don't know if this could be applied to this case. Also the user-created filters should be applied consecutively, i.e, if user creates three filters, then filter1 should be applied, then filter2, and then filter3.

I have this little example app where there is an initial filter based on `Person` using `textAreaInput` (my final user would like to paste some names on the box to filter out the table) but I would like to add some another filters, for example a `sliderInput` for `votes` or a dropdownMenu for `letters`.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

header <- dashboardHeader(title="Analysis and database")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
   # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
    id = "sidebarmenu",
    menuItem("Database", tabName="db"),
    menuItem("Search by Name", tabName = "Filt_table"),
      textAreaInput("name_", "Name")
 )
)

body <- dashboardBody(

 tabItems(
  tabItem("db","table content",
        fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput('tabla'))),
  tabItem("Filt_table","Filtered table content",
        fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput('tablafilt')))
 )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

### SERVER SIDE

server = function(input, output, session) {

my_data <- data.frame(Person=c("Anne", "Pete", "Rose", "Julian", "Tristan", "Hugh"), 
Votes=c(10,25,56,89.36,78,1500), 
Stuff=c("test|3457678", "exterm|4567sdf", "1001(hom);4.3.4|3456", "xdfrtg", "1234|trsef|456(het)", "hyggas|tertasga"),
 letters=replicate(6, paste(sample(LETTERS,6, replace=T), collapse="")))

output$tabla <- DT::renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable(my_data)
})

filtered <- reactive({
  if(is.null(input$name_))
    return()  
    glist <- isolate(input$name_)
    filter(my_data, Person %in% glist)
 })

output$tablafilt <- DT::renderDataTable({
  if(is.null(input$name_))
    return()  

   DT::datatable(filtered (), 
              filter = 'top', 
              extensions = 'Buttons',
              options = list(
                dom = 'Blftip',
                buttons = 
                  list('colvis', list(
                    extend = 'collection',
                    buttons = list(list(extend='csv',
                                        filename = 'results'),
                                   list(extend='excel',
                                        filename = 'results'),
                                   list(extend='pdf',
                                        filename= 'results')),
                    text = 'Download'
                  )),
                scrollX = TRUE,
                pageLength = 5,
                lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), list('5', '15', 'All'))
              ), rownames = FALSE
    )
  })



}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: just to be sure. I see that you are using the argument filter = "top" (although it doesnt appear in your example). How would the desired renderUI() functionality differ from the filter argument in the datatable? See 2.8 in https://rstudio.github.io/DT/.

Comment: @BigDataScientist, thanks for the comment, actually my desired renderUi() should imitate the functionality of `top`. the problem is that my actual table has 140 columns, and the users don't want to scroll horizontally to apply a filter and sometimes in `DT` with so many columns the scroll doesn't work very well and the data doesn't fit properly. The problem is also that some user would want to filter for several columns and other user would filter by other ones. So the idea is let the user create filters (numeric, by factor, etc) according to column names, besides the `texInputArea` is common

Comment: makes perfect sense, thx for the clarification!

Comment: This look a lot like what I'm trying to achieve, have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54114153/generic-data-filter-ui-in-shiny and the linked SO that have a working version of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by creating a `selectInput()` for all variables as well as add and remove buttons:

```
  output$potentialFilter <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      selectInput("createFilter", "Create Filter", names(my_data)),
      actionButton("remove", "remove"),
      actionButton("add", "add")
    )
  })
```

And then you can create inputs for the selected variables.
Note: As you dont want to reset the inserted UIs when you add new ones you should use `insertUI()` instead of `renderUI()`.

```
  insertUI(selector = "#add", where = "afterEnd", 
           ui = selectizeInput(toBeIncluded, toBeIncluded, my_data[[toBeIncluded]], 
                               selected = my_data[[toBeIncluded]], multiple = TRUE)
  )
```

**Full example would read:**

```
  library(shinydashboard)
  library(dplyr)
  library(shiny)
  library(DT)

  header <- dashboardHeader(title="Analysis and database")

  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
      id = "sidebarmenu",
      menuItem("Database", tabName="db"),
      menuItem("Search by Name", tabName = "Filt_table"),
      uiOutput("potentialFilter"),
      uiOutput("rendFilter")
    )
  )

  body <- dashboardBody(

    tabItems(
      tabItem("db","table content",
              fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput('tabla'))),
      tabItem("Filt_table","Filtered table content",
              fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput('tablafilt')))
    )
  )

  ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

  ### SERVER SIDE

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    my_data <- data.frame(Person=c("Anne", "Pete", "Rose", "Julian", "Tristan", "Hugh"), 
                          Votes=c(10,25,56,89.36,78,1500), 
                          Stuff=c("test|3457678", "exterm|4567sdf", "1001(hom);4.3.4|3456", "xdfrtg", "1234|trsef|456(het)", "hyggas|tertasga"),
                          letters=replicate(6, paste(sample(LETTERS,6, replace=T), collapse="")),
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    global <- reactiveValues(filter = c(), filteredData = my_data, tagList = tagList())

    output$potentialFilter <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        selectInput("createFilter", "Create Filter", names(my_data)),
        actionButton("remove", "remove"),
        actionButton("add", "add")
      )
    })


    observeEvent(input$add, {
      global$filter <- c(global$filter, input$createFilter)
      toBeIncluded <- input$createFilter
      data <- my_data[[toBeIncluded]]
      if(typeof(data) == "double"){
        ui <- numericInput(toBeIncluded, toBeIncluded, ceiling(min(data)), min = min(data), max = max(data))
      }else if(typeof(data) == "character"){
        ui <- textAreaInput(toBeIncluded, toBeIncluded, data[1], width = "200px")
      }
      insertUI(selector = "#add", where = "afterEnd", ui = ui)
    })

    observeEvent(input$remove, {  
      global$filter <- setdiff(global$filter, input$createFilter)
      removeUI(selector = paste0("div:has(> #", input$createFilter, ")"))
    })

    output$tabla <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(filtered())
    })

    filtered <- reactive({
      if(length(global$filter)){
        for(filterName in global$filter){
          if(is.character(input[[filterName]])){
            names <- unlist(strsplit(input[[filterName]], ";"))
            my_data <- my_data[my_data[[filterName]] %in% names, ]           
          }else if(is.numeric(input[[filterName]])){
            my_data <- my_data[my_data[[filterName]] >= input[[filterName]], ] 
          }
        }
      }
      return(my_data)
    })

    output$tablafilt <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(filtered(), 
                    filter = 'top', 
                    extensions = 'Buttons',
                    options = list(
                      dom = 'Blftip',
                      buttons = 
                        list('colvis', list(
                          extend = 'collection',
                          buttons = list(list(extend='csv',
                                              filename = 'results'),
                                         list(extend='excel',
                                              filename = 'results'),
                                         list(extend='pdf',
                                              filename= 'results')),
                          text = 'Download'
                        )),
                      scrollX = TRUE,
                      pageLength = 5,
                      lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), list('5', '15', 'All'))
                    ), rownames = FALSE
      )
    })



  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

(I am not sure it makes a difference in which order you apply the filter, maybe you can ellaborate on this if I am mistaken).

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, but the "desired" behaviour would be that filters are applied consecutively, i.e, if I apply a filter by "Person", and then a filter by "Votes", only the  persons selected using Person filter would be filtered by vote. Now, if I click two "newly created" filters, the first is reset and the full table is displayed. Also, is there a way to use another option for `selectizeInput`, my real data has 20,000 rows and `selectizeInput` display all the options. If is too much question, the consecutive filter would be enough. Thanks

Comment: sry, i got sick. I might be able to take a look, later this week.

Comment: @BigSataScientist did you have a change to look to this question again?

Comment: left the bed again today ;) I made an update. I am not sure about your `selectizeInput` specification. Would you replace the `selectInput("createFilter", "Create Filter", names(my_data))` (top of my post) with a text input or how would you approach the 20k row challenge?

Comment: hope you are better @BigDataScientist, the `selectInput` could be a subset of columns, although the dataset has more than 100 columns the user usually wants to filter by 5-10 at most

Comment: ok, if i understand correctly, that can be achieved with the current code. Is your questions answered or are there open issues?

Comment: yep, now the filter works, but is there any easy way to change the filter based on the value in the table?, i.e, for numeric values, instead of display all the values (30K values), it could be a slider, and for characters just a textArea where you can type and filter those values you type? I thinking of my big table when  ~30k values when a filter is created

Comment: ah yeah, thats what i also wondered. I made an edit. You can add multiple names with ";" (semicolon) as a seperator,..

Comment: Thanks @BigDataScientist, it works nicely, I have a small question, in the `textArea` if i want to introduce the names by rows instead of using a semicolon, should I would need to change this line right `names <- unlist(strsplit(input[[filterName]], ";"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can always update your filters on the spot by using

updateSelectInput and others

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.13.2/updateSelectInput.html

Best!